# Iterating through JSON using angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am having a JSON string that contains all my parent and child nodes. I need to render the parent node and its corresponding child nodes as a list in the navigation bar.

Here is my json:

```
    [
      {node_ID='2', name='Child3', parent='3', role ='leafNode'},
      {node_ID='4', name='Child4', parent='3', role ='leafNode'},
      {node_ID='3', name='Child2', parent='1', role ='Node'},
      {node_ID='1', name='Node1', parent='0', role ='rootNode'},
```

... ]

After Iterating my list should be displayed as:

```
          > Node1
            >Child2
              >Child3
              >Child4
```

Can someone provide solution for it using angular.forEach function to traverse along the JSIN array and sort the nodes based on their node-ID and Parent-ID ??

Comment: Do you control the data sent from back end? Sending flat array isn't nearly as clean as sending nested arrays with same property keys at each level. Please also show attempts to solve this

Comment: Yes, trying to control data coming from backend. Tried using for.Each function but it didn't render as per the parent child relationship.

Comment: @Sree you can do parent child relationship to array in JavaScript too. If not getting solution from backend. It should be like       {
       node_ID = '1', name = 'Node1', role = 'rootNode', child = [{
        node_ID = '3', name = 'Child2', role = 'Node', child = [{
         node_ID = '2', name = 'Child3', role = 'leafNode', child = []
        }, {
         node_ID = '4', name = 'Child4', role = 'leafNode', child = []
        }]
       }]
      },

Comment: show us what you tried even if it's not working. That's the whole idea of this site....you show the code that is giving problems, people try to help you fix it. Without seeing some effort it then appears you are asking others to do all of your work for you. It might be something simple you need...in which case it means we don't have to build it from nothing

Comment: Also suggest you google `angular recursive directive`

Comment: @Charlietfl here is the code am trying     angular.forEach($scope.nodeList, function(parentNode){ if(item.parent===0) { console.log(parentNode.name);}

Answer (score 2):

This will map your data into a nested array suitable for passing to a recursive tree directive. It shouldn't be hard to find one of those in a web search...there are lots and lots of examples and modules

```
var tmp ={}, res=[];

data.forEach(function(item){
   item.children =[];
   tmp[item.node_ID]=item;
});

data.forEach(function(item){
  if(+item.parent !==0){
    tmp[item.parent].children.push(item);
  }else{
    res.push(item);
  }
});

delete tmp;


$scope.tree = res;
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/X7D0cUrEsgZ5dtdTTKfj?p=preview)</kbd>